# no esta definido require fs

Tags: nodejs

Tengo una duda muy grande, estoy queriendo escribir desde un script de js un archivo json con un array dentro del archivo json, pero cuando ejecuto ese script me dice que el require no esta definido.

```
var accesorio = document.getElementById("accesorios");
    var pieza = document.getElementById("piezas");
    //const pieza=document.querySelector('#piezas');
    carrito.push(accesorio.value);
    carrito.push(pieza.value);
    console.log(carrito);
    // convertimos el array en un json para enviarlo al PHP
    var arrayJson=JSON.stringify(carrito);
    console.log(arrayJson);
    'use strict';
    var fs = require('fs'). requirejs;
    fs.writeFile("carrito.json",arrayJson , function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

cuado de mi pagina dodne llamo este scriot me marca

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Si estas llamando el script desde la página en el navegador, esta función no está definida porque esta es una función exclusiva de [tag:node].

Comment: a ok, pero entocnes realice esta prueba: realice un scriot de js con el siguiente codigo var fs = require('fs').requirejs;
    fs.writeFile('data.txt', 'arrayJson', (error) =>{
    if(error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error}`);
    }
}); y al ejecutarlo desde la terminal mesale una ventana que dice error de sintaxis codigo 800a03ea error de compilacion

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes! El código va EN la pregunta, yendo a [edit]. Acá abajo es ilegible, como puedes ver. Añade pruebas adicionales y errores allá, en la pregunta, manteniendo la pregunta y mostrando la evolución de la misma

Comment: `require` es para módulos de nodejs. De todos modos lo que quieres hacer (guardar información a un archivo del lado del cliente) no se puede hacer. Para eso puedes usar [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: a ok, gracias por la info, pero creo ahora tengo poco mas de duas jejeje, entonces si necesito guardar ese arreglo desde mi cliente para que luego yo lo pueda leer con php desde mi servidor, esto lo puedo hacer con el localstorege?

Comment: Si quieres leerlo desde el servidor tendrás que pasarselo en un pedido POST